# Returning after throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, return-value, throw

Is it in any way beneficial to `return` a value after `throw`ing an exception? If not, can the `return` statement be left out and is it somehow possible to remove compiler error `C4715: not all control paths return a value`?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: (sample code)

```
for (ushort i = 0; i < itsNumUnits; ++i)
    if (unitFormation[i] == unit)
    {
        return unitSetup[i];
    }
    else
        throw unit;

return 0;
```

Comment: If the last statement in your routine is a `throw` and you're still getting a warning, maybe you should post a code sample and say which compiler you're using.

Comment: What I had in mind was something of the sort that I added in the question... Sorry didn't add a sample before.

Comment: The compiler warning is not a problem with the language or the Standard, but with the compiler.  I assume you're using some version of Visual C++ from the form of the error message, but it might help to know which one.

Comment: The example code will only look at the first unit in the formation, and either return or throw before iterating the loop. Is that really what you want? If so, why is the loop there at all?

Comment: This is VS2010. Yes, that bit of code is from a function which is given a pointer. The function checks within a member array to see of that pointer exists, and if it does, returns another value associated with that pointer. If it doesn't, (and this shouldn't occur) it throws the pointer (I haven't implemented an actual exception class yet).

The code after the throw statement can never be reached.

Comment: Wait... I got it all wrong heh! Ooops *blush*

You're right Mike.. That `else` was extra!

Comment: Do you still get the warning without the extra `else`?

Comment: Nope. Having said that, the code could not have reached that part of the code anyway, so why the compiler grumbling?

Comment: @Kristian: if `itsNumUnits` were zero, then it would skip to the end of the function, so there was a valid code path without a return. It does pay to heed warnings; they often point to genuine errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to return a value after exception throw. If you have this error, you should check the paths your code can get to without throwing an exception, e.g.

```
if (something)
    throw Exception;
else
    return value;
```

Failing to return value in the "else" branch of "if" would cause a compile error because the exception may or may not be thrown depending on value of `something`.

Comment: MSVC will give C4715: not all control paths return a value for the if path in your code, even though this path cannot return since it always throws.

Answer (score 2):

throw itself terminates the function execution. But if your function returns a value, and the exception is not thrown, you'll have to take care of returning a value. E.g.:

```
bool foo(bool _flag) throw(...)
{
    if (_flag)
    {
        throw "foo is throwing an exception";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to being able to "return" a value as well as throw an exception is when the function writes to a pointer or referenced object before throwing the exception:

```
void my_func(int& ret)
{
    ret = 0;

    for (ushort i = 0; i < itsNumUnits; ++i) {
        if (unitFormation[i] == unit) {
            ret = unitSetup[i];
            return;
        }
        else {
            throw unit;
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern, however, is error-prone and rarely useful. Think carefully before using it.

Answer (score -1):

After throw you end up in catch (the code below throw is not executed). The only block that is executed is the finally.

If you want to achieve something like what you described above go for something like this:

```
object returnVal = null; // the bad
try
{
    //some code here
    throw new Exception(); // something bad happened
    //some more code
    returnVal = new object(); // the good
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // log, try to recover etc.
    // maybe it`s a good idea not to throw it away if you can handle it here!
}
return returnVal; // either the good or the bad (never the ugly!)
```

The C# equivalent of the warning is a compiler error so in any way I don't think a good idea is to get rid of compiler warnings but to try to solve them.

Regards...

Comment: There's no `finally` in C++, and the question has no mention of catching the exception. And if the compiler is generating a warning due to not having a `return` after an unconditional `throw`, then the warning is bogus.

Comment: Very bad code for C++, we don't have `object`, `null`, or `new` all over the place...