# Throw exception and return result from a function

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I'm just learning C++, and would like to throw an exception, but then the result of my function would be undefined???

```
 std::vector<myStruct> extract_notworking(std::vector<myStruct>& avec){
        std::vector<myStruct> result;

        if (avec.size() == 0)
            //throw domain_error("Cannot operate on empty vector!");
            //Cannot use exception for it would yield undefined result
            return result;

        //do something here
        //...
        return result;
    }
```

What should I do? Return an empty vector? What would happen if I threw the exception to the receiver of the return value?

Comment: If you throw an exception, then your function does not return.  That's the whole point.

Comment: So maybe make my function void and add another parameter by reference to my vector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning after throwing exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109943/returning-after-throwing-exceptions)

Comment: @Mihaela: The point of an exception is that control will immediately jump to wherever the exception is caught.  Your function will not return, and the piece of code that called your function will not be run (so it won't matter that there is no return value).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you throw an exception, the function halts there and execution jumps to wherever the exception was caught. Your function doesn't return anything because the function doesn't return at all.

You can just do

```
if (avec.empty())
    throw domain_error("Cannot operate on empty vector!");
```

And your function will exit there.

Note that you don't need to be concerned about the return value ("How can a function not return anything?" etc) because you can't access the return value of a function that threw (and did not catch) an exception even if you try.

So for instance, if you do

```
try {
    std::vector<myStruct> vec;

    std::vector<myStruct> retval = extract_notworking(vec);

    print_vector(retval); // this line is only executed if extract_networking
                          // does not throw an exception
} catch (const domain_error& e) {
    // we can't access retval here so no worries
}
```

You can only access `retval` if the function returns properly (i.e. does not throw). In the example, your function will throw because `vec` is empty, so `print_vector` will never be called.

Even if you do this:

```
std::vector<myStruct> retval;

try {
    std::vector<myStruct> vec;

    retval = extract_notworking(vec);

    print_vector(retval);
} catch (const domain_error& e) {
    // we can access retval here but the assignment never happened
}
```

Since the function did not return, the assignment of its return value to `retval` did not happen, and `retval` is still a perfectly normal default-constructed `vector` that you can use freely. So in that example, `retval` is not assigned to and `retval` is not printed, because `extract_networking` threw an exception and execution jumped into the `catch` block before those two things could happen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll throw the exception, and catch it in the caller.

Answer (score 4):

When you `throw` an exception, you cannot `return`, and vice versa. You can think of exceptions as a generalised `return` designed for exceptional circumstances and errors. Consider this function:

```
int f(bool b) {
    if (b)
        return 42;
    throw std::runtime_error("Runtime error!");
}
```

When we call it, we can capture its *normal* return value (in this case an `int`) in an expression, or we can capture its *exceptional* return value (`std::runtime_error`) using a `try` block with a `catch` of the correct type:

```
try {

    int normal_result = f(b);

    // Use normal result.
    // (Exceptional result does not exist.)
    std::cout << normal_result << '\n';

} catch (const std::exception& exceptional_result) {

    // Use exceptional result.
    // (Normal result does not exist.)
    std::cout << exceptional_result.what() << '\n';

}
```

The power of exceptions, of course, comes from the fact that they propagate up the call stack until they reach a matching `catch`. Thus you can use them to escape from deeply nested function calls, while ensuring that your resources (memory, files, &c.) are correctly managed.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do? Return an empty vector? What would happen if I threw the exception to the receiver of the return value?

What is returned from a function is irrelevant, since the return value is not going to be used in any way. The execution will continue at the next catch for that particular exception (off course after unwinding the stack).