# Don't need a return after throw - standard or compiler specific?

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-compiling, portability

If I have function like this

```
int f()
{
   //something
   if ()
   {
      //something
      return 1;
   }

   throw std::runtime_error("msg");
}
```

In Visual studio in compiles ok and works as expected, but is it a standard thing that after throw I don't need a return statement, or it can lead to some error on other compilers?

Comment: Or [Throw exception and return result from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549493/throw-exception-and-return-result-from-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one important detail, and this is: Also this would compile without compiler errors

```
int f_wrong() {}  // Wrong!
```

It does not produce a compiler error, but calling the function invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Also this is "ok-ish" when it is never called with a `false` parameter:

```
int f_still_wrong(bool x) {  
     if(x) return 42;
}
```

Generally we want to write code that cannot cause undefined behavior at runtime. The compiler warning you get when a function is missing a return can help with that.

That being said, what matters is whether there is a path the falls of the end of the function without returning. In the case of

```
int f_ok(bool x) {
     if (x) return 42;
     throw 42;
     // (1)
}
```

There are two possiblities: 1) It returns 42, 2) it throws, stack is unwound and statements after the `throw` are not executed. There is no way the function can return without returning a value. `(1)` is unreachable code, placing a `return` at `(1)` can be misleading, and compilers might warn about uncreachable code. The function `f_ok` is ok.

Answer (score 2):

After a throw, execution of the current function is aborted, unless the exception is caught. Thus, any code after an uncaught throw will never be reached, making a `return` superfluous.

It works both ways: a throw after a return in the same execution branch is similarly unreachable — both of these statements will terminate the function's execution.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` after `throw` will be unreachable code. It will never be executed.